# How to make a TCP source reconnect in GNU radio?

Tags: python, sockets, gnuradio

How do you make a TCP source server reconnect in GNU radio? Once you have connected a client once, it cannot accept new connections. Having studied `tcp.py` it is obvious that this is because the python part only calls `accept` once.

This issue was asked before on a mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2010-04/msg00501.html but the answer was slightly unsatisfactory, because it was supposedly easy to do with some "dup magic".

I managed to make a reconnecting socket using the file descriptor as an identifier in Python in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import socket
import sys
import threading

def get_server_socket_and_fd():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9999))
    s.listen(1)
    print "waiting for client connection on port 9999"
    cs, address = s.accept()
    return s, os.dup(cs.fileno())

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

class SocketWatcher(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, server_socket, fd):
        super(SocketWatcher, self).__init__()
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self._fd = fd
        self._server_socket = server_socket

    def run(self):
        print "WWW: starting watcher on fd = {}".format(self._fd)
        while not self.stopped():
            #print "WWW: creating socket object from fd = {}".format(self._fd)
            s = socket.fromfd(self._fd, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            while not self.stopped():
                print "WWW: trying to peek for new data"
                data = s.recv(1024, socket.MSG_PEEK)
                print "WWW: msg peek returned: {} bytes".format(len(data))
                if len(data) == 0:
                    print "WWW: EOF? closing socket"
                    s.close()
                    print "WWW: waiting for new connection..."
                    cs, address = self._server_socket.accept()
                    print "WWW: new connection! fileno = {}".format(cs.fileno())
                    print "WWW: duplicating this client socket fd into the old one"
                    os.dup2(cs.fileno(), self._fd)
                    break
        print "WWW: thread stopped, exiting run method"

server_socket, client_fd = get_server_socket_and_fd()

watcher = SocketWatcher(server_socket, client_fd)
watcher.start()

try:
    while True:
        s = socket.fromfd(client_fd, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if len(data) > 0:
            print "    data received: {} bytes".format(len(data))
            print repr(data)            

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print "stopping program..."
    watcher.stop()
    sys.exit()
```

which works like expected: start python script, connect to the port, write things, close connection, open another connection, write more things, and notice that they continue to be printed.

However, when I try to integrate this into GNU radio: it does not work. This is my best attempt:

```
#
# Copyright 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# This file is part of GNU Radio
#
# GNU Radio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
# any later version.
#
# GNU Radio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GNU Radio; see the file COPYING.  If not, write to
# the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street,
# Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#

from gnuradio import gr, blocks
import socket
import os
import threading

class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()

class SocketWatcher(StoppableThread):
    def __init__(self, server_socket, fd):
        super(SocketWatcher, self).__init__()
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self._fd = fd
        self._server_socket = server_socket

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped():
            s = socket.fromfd(self._fd, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            while not self.stopped():
                data = s.recv(1024, socket.MSG_PEEK)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    print "EOF detected. Closing socket and waiting for new connection..."
                    s.close()
                    cs, address = self._server_socket.accept()
                    print "got new connection!"
                    os.dup2(cs.fileno(), self._fd)
                    break


def _get_sock_fd(addr, port, server):
    """
    Get the file descriptor for the socket.
    As a client, block on connect, dup the socket descriptor.
    As a server, block on accept, dup the client descriptor.

    Args:
        addr: the ip address string
        port: the tcp port number
        server: true for server mode, false for client mode

    Returns:
        the file descriptor number
    """
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if server:
        sock.bind((addr, port))
        sock.listen(1)
        clientsock, address = sock.accept()
        return os.dup(clientsock.fileno()), sock
    else:
        sock.connect((addr, port))
        return os.dup(sock.fileno()), sock

class tcp_source(gr.hier_block2):
    def __init__(self, itemsize, addr, port, server=True):
        #init hier block
        gr.hier_block2.__init__(
            self, 'tcp_source',
            gr.io_signature(0, 0, 0),
            gr.io_signature(1, 1, itemsize),
        )
        if not server:
            raise NotImplementedError
        fd, server_socket = _get_sock_fd(addr, port, server)
        watcher = SocketWatcher(server_socket, fd)
        watcher.start()
        self.connect(blocks.file_descriptor_source(itemsize, fd), self)

class tcp_sink(gr.hier_block2):
    def __init__(self, itemsize, addr, port, server=False):
        #init hier block
        gr.hier_block2.__init__(
            self, 'tcp_sink',
            gr.io_signature(1, 1, itemsize),
            gr.io_signature(0, 0, 0),
        )
        fd, _ = _get_sock_fd(addr, port, server)
        self.connect(self, blocks.file_descriptor_sink(itemsize, fd))
```

I do see on the command line:

```
EOF detected. Closing socket and waiting for new connection...
got new connection!
```

which suggests that detecting EOF was successful, however, once I reconnect the connection is accepted, but whatever I write to the socket does not appear on the other end. I use a simple GNU radio program to test this, consisting of a TCP source (my version of it), a throttle and a TCP sink.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<?grc format='1' created='3.7.8'?>
<flow_graph>
  <timestamp>Fri Dec 18 14:18:32 2015</timestamp>
  <block>
    <key>options</key>
    <param>
      <key>author</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>window_size</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>category</key>
      <value>Custom</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>comment</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>description</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_enabled</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_coordinate</key>
      <value>(8, 8)</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_rotation</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>generate_options</key>
      <value>qt_gui</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>id</key>
      <value>top_block</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>max_nouts</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>realtime_scheduling</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>run_options</key>
      <value>prompt</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>run</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>thread_safe_setters</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>title</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
  </block>
  <block>
    <key>variable</key>
    <param>
      <key>comment</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_enabled</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_coordinate</key>
      <value>(8, 160)</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_rotation</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>id</key>
      <value>samp_rate</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>value</key>
      <value>32000</value>
    </param>
  </block>
  <block>
    <key>blks2_tcp_sink</key>
    <param>
      <key>addr</key>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>alias</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>comment</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>affinity</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_enabled</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_coordinate</key>
      <value>(696, 125)</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_rotation</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>id</key>
      <value>blks2_tcp_sink_0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>type</key>
      <value>complex</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>server</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>port</key>
      <value>9001</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>vlen</key>
      <value>1</value>
    </param>
  </block>
  <block>
    <key>blks2_tcp_source</key>
    <param>
      <key>addr</key>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>alias</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>comment</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>affinity</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_enabled</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_coordinate</key>
      <value>(344, 136)</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_rotation</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>id</key>
      <value>blks2_tcp_source_0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>maxoutbuf</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>minoutbuf</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>server</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>type</key>
      <value>complex</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>port</key>
      <value>9000</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>vlen</key>
      <value>1</value>
    </param>
  </block>
  <block>
    <key>blocks_throttle</key>
    <param>
      <key>alias</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>comment</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>affinity</key>
      <value></value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_enabled</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_coordinate</key>
      <value>(536, 112)</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>_rotation</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>id</key>
      <value>blocks_throttle_0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>ignoretag</key>
      <value>True</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>maxoutbuf</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>minoutbuf</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>samples_per_second</key>
      <value>samp_rate</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>type</key>
      <value>complex</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <key>vlen</key>
      <value>1</value>
    </param>
  </block>
  <connection>
    <source_block_id>blks2_tcp_source_0</source_block_id>
    <sink_block_id>blocks_throttle_0</sink_block_id>
    <source_key>0</source_key>
    <sink_key>0</sink_key>
  </connection>
  <connection>
    <source_block_id>blocks_throttle_0</source_block_id>
    <sink_block_id>blks2_tcp_sink_0</sink_block_id>
    <source_key>0</source_key>
    <sink_key>0</sink_key>
  </connection>
</flow_graph>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be completely honest, I always felt the `tcp_sink` and `_source` were but incomplete hacks, mostly done to show how it was easy to do something fast and rudimentary rather than right; notice the copyright year, no one really tried to improve this approach for at least the last 6 years, and that's mainly because it's pretty incomplete. There's been [quite some problems](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-05/msg00125.html), among those, as you probably noticed, the fact that the constructor just blocks for as long as there's no connection, instead of letting the other blocks also be instantiated and then blocking in its `work` until it can consume samples.

I'm not completely sure what goes wrong here, but this might very well be a python multithreading problem -- the GNU Radio scheduler spawns an own thread for every signal processing block, and it's not always transparent to python in what context to call functions of blocks.

So, the first question is: do you need *networking* or *TCP* specifically? If you need any well-working, stateless server, use the UDP ones; they are implemented using asynchronous IO and work pretty reliably. If you need elegant, integrity-guaranteeing networking, try the zeroMQ blocks.

Assuming you **really** want TCP:

I think your best course of action would actually be throwing away the existing hier_block and `file_descriptor_sink` based approach and simply handle connections in your own python or C++ sink block.

That's not really hard; you seem to be proficient enough at writing GNU Radio python blocks, but as reference (and for later readers), I'd like to point you to the [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials) that after a quick introduction to SDR in general and GRC usage introduce you to writing Python blocks.

Generally, it boils to

1. Generating an out-of-tree module `gr_modtool newmod`
2. `cd <modulename>`
3. Adding a python sink block `gr_modtool add`
4. modifying that block to have the right `io_signature`, and to have a meaningful `work` function, i.e. one

   - that checks for an existing TCP connection,
   - tries to send the samples the work is called with,
   - returns the number of items sent if > 0,
   - attempts to build a new connection if there's no connection, and blocks until at least one item has been sent